Gitlab CI-CD: передать файл в докер контейнер
Подскажите как мне забрать файл во время выполнения pipline и передать его в докер контейнер?
docker-compose
services:
  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    #build: .
    container_name: gitlab-runner-container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8093:8093
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - gitlab-runner-config:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - .:/home/gitlab-runner

volumes:
  gitlab-runner-config

.gitlab-cy.yml
stages:
  - test-pull

deploy test:
  stage: test-pull
  script:
    - echo "$(date)" >> Test.txt
    - cp -r Test.txt /www123

Не понимаю как передать файл из gitlab-cy в докер контейнер. Добавил в config.toml такую строку:
volumes = ["/cache","/home/gitlab-runner/prod:/www123:rw"]

Используйте docker cp

Ругается, : /bin/bash: line 148: docker: command not found.

Очевидно, что вам необходим докер, установленный в контейнере, выполняющем pipeline

Как оказалось не внимательно читал манула. Мне пришлось исправить в config.toml следующие пункты:  image = "docker:24.0.5" - нельзя использовать latest privileged = true - д.б. обязательно включен
